# What is a reliable way to change PostgreSQL configuration, especially move its data directory in a script?

Tags: postgresql, sed, configuration-files, docker

#### What I want to Achieve

For packaging some software together with PostgreSQL in a docker container, I want to change PostgreSQL's `data_directory` together with all other persistent data to `/srv`.

Background information:

- PostgreSQL is freshly set up using `apt-get`
- the `postgresql` service was never started at that point
- My aim is to move have the persistent data in `/srv` without getting in trouble later. I don't care for how this is achieved, setting `data_directory` just seems most appropriate to me.

#### Thoughts on the Problem

- I could just use `sed` to modify `postgresql.conf`, for example like this:

  ```
  $ sed -i 's#^\(data_directory\s*=\s*\).*$#\1/srv/postgresql/main#'\
    /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
  ```

  But I don't really like messing around in configuration files with scripts if there is a better way. I found a rather huge [perl script for modifying PostgreSQL configuration files](https://github.com/bucardo/modify_postgres_config), but I'm somewhat scared to embed this without being able to fully understand what it's doing in five minutes.
- I'm not surprised that changing from within a running system using `psql` and the `SET` SQL command fails:

  ```
  postgres=# set data_directory to '/srv/postgresql/main';
  ERROR:  parameter "data_directory" cannot be changed without restarting the server
  ```
- [`pg_config`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-pgconfig.html) on the other hand is only able to print information and not installed anyway.

#### And now?

Often, there are convenient and reliable tools to set options, does PostgreSQL also ship one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention `apt-get` as the way of installing, it means we're talking about PostgreSQL as packaged for Debian and its derivatives.

In Debian, the PostgreSQL data location is set by creating a cluster like this:

```
# pg_createcluster --datadir=/path/to/data [other options] version name
```

where version is a major version as in `9.1` and `name` a short name of your choice identifiying this cluster. It actually puts data structures inside the directory, as opposed to just changing a line in `postgresql.conf` which by itself would be useless.

When running `apt-get install postgresql` or a variant implying to install a new PG server, it implicitly creates and starts a cluster whose name is `main` and datadir is `/usr/lib/postgresql/<version>/main`

You want to remove that cluster **before creating another one** to have only one cluster running, example with 9.1:

```
# pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main
```